# SQL error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. unable to find in other answers

Tags: sql

SQL error received, any suggestions?

error:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

```
USE Intranet
DECLARE @StartDate date,
        @EndDate date

SET @StartDate = '6/1/2023'
SET @EndDate = '6/30/2023'

SELECT
a.CompanyID AS 'COID',
a.LocationID AS 'Location',
SUM((ISNULL(a.ShipQty, 0)) * (ISNULL(a.UnitPrice, 0))) WHERE a.DocumentType IN ('INInvoice', 'OEInvoice', 'WOInvoice')
--ELSE 0 END AS 'Original Sell Invoiced'

FROM DF_OrderLine as a
LEFT JOIN VibeNetProductClass as b
ON b.CompanyID = a.CompanyID
AND b.ProductClassID = a.ProductClassID
WHERE CAST(a.InvoiceDate AS date) >= @StartDate
AND CAST(a.InvoiceDate AS date) <= @EndDate

GROUP BY 
a.CompanyID,
a.LocationID
```

Comment: You seem to have a random WHERE clause in the middle of your SELECT clause

Comment: Yes, suggestion is to check this on your own. There is nothing simpler than analyze why a query is invalid. Remove line by line and see when the query becomes valid.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?